# How to retrieve the total cases in my data set on a MongoDB query?

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I want the total number of cases in all my documents,

This is the query I tried to use:

```
db.coviddatajson.aggregate([ 
  { $group: { _id: null, total: { $sum: "$total_cases"} } } 
])
```

For some reason the result is 0 which does not make sense, as it's supposed to be 1000+ at least and the expected result anything that is not zero will make sense but it's supposed to be a few thousands or something like that.

This is the dataset I am using:
https://covid.ourworldindata.org/data/owid-covid-data.json

What am I doing wrong here?
Any ideas on how to fix this query?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow, can you add sample documents and expected result in your question.

Comment: Update this details in your question, take a SO [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and see [how-to-ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Do you really like to sum up **all** total_cases? In the `data` element you have a set per day. Sum up all of them given does no make much sense. Either take the value from last day inside the `data` (which in general could be different for each country) or you would need to sum `new_cases` in order to get the correct number of total cases.

Comment: How did you insert the data into your MongoDB? Exactly as provided by the JSON file? Please provide some sample data (i.e. just 1-2 countries and 2-3 days each)

Comment: If you would have a look at the data set, then you should see that you don't need any aggregation. Simply select data for `db.coviddatajson.find({ location: "World" })` Otherwise it should be excluded from sum.

Answer (score 1):

The `total_cases` field is inside `data` array, and `$sum` requires field type as number in `$group` stage, so before we need to do total($sum) of `data.total_cases` in current document and then pass it to `$group` stage and count total sum,

```
db.coviddatajson.aggregate([ 
  {
    $project: { total_cases: { $sum: "$data.total_cases" } }
  },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: null,
      total: { $sum: "$total_cases" }
    }
  }
])
```

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/yZ95s7Ybvvy)

Comment: why did you put data.total_cases?

Comment: it is inside `data` key that you provided in your json file.

Comment: the other option is: db.coviddatajson.aggregate([{$unwind:"$data"} , {$group:{ _id:null , total:{ $sum:"$data.total_cases"   }}}   ])

Comment: @kiko075 it is too heavy transaction when huge data, i can see there are lots of data in OP's json file.

Comment: @turvishal:  Yes , indeed this with the project stage looks abit more effective especially if you add also _id:0 for bigger arrays and more documents ...

Comment: The root element are the country short names (depending how the data was inserted into MongoDB collection). You may need `$replaceRoot` and `$unwind` before you can run `{ $sum: "$data.total_cases" }`

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit i see thanks, i missed it, let's see OP's opinion, and requirement first.

Comment: @Mika Some of the json docs here https://covid.ourworldindata.org/data/owid-covid-data.json  bigger then  16MB , how you succeded to import to mongodb  ?

Answer (score 1):

The data set has some issues.

- The document size is bigger than 16MiB, you cannot load documents >16MiB into MongoDB. This in an internal limitation. You would need to split the document into sub-documents.
- The document contains data for each country but also summarized data for "World". Do you have to exclude the "World" data? Can you use it, instead of manual summary?
- The data is not consistent. For example some countries do not provide a number of male/female smokers or median age. Not all countries provide all data for each date, you may have missing values. How to deal with them?

Do you like a **simple sum of all total_cases**? If yes, the query would be easy, however the result would be pointless (15'773'189'214 total cases, twice population of the world).